# Phoenix setup failing due to space in filepath

Tags: macos, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to set up the [demo Phoenix project](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/up-and-running) and I can't get past the step where I run `mix ecto.create`.

This is the error I get:

```
sh: /Volumes/1: No such file or directory
** (Mix) Could not compile dependency :fs, "/Volumes/1 TB HDD WD/Users/__USERNAME__/.mix/rebar compile skip_deps=true deps_dir="/Volumes/1 TB HDD WD/Users/__USERNAME__/.../hello_phoenix/_build/dev/lib"" command failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile fs", update it with "mix deps.update fs" or clean it with "mix deps.clean fs"
```

It really looks like it's because of the spaces in my hard drive name, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Are you on Mac or Linux?

Comment: @gage have you tried running the commands listed in the error? It's worth giving it a shot - `mix deps.compile fs` `mix deps.update` `mix deps.clean`. I don't think the space in the volume should be an issue

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci The capitalized `Volumes` and `Users` suggests OS X to me.